# How do I invoke a WCF operationcontract using a messagecontract?

Tags: wcf

From several examples I've followed
CalculateDetails1() is declared with a parameter 'CuboidInfoRequest' 
of Type Message Contract 
which contains a DataContractObject named Dimension as type CuboidDimension as its only property.

Why is CalculateDetails1 invoked and the client proxy generated with parameterized properties of the CuboidInfoRequest 
instead of the message contract object itself?!

And can't it return another MessageContract type again composed of another datacontract ?   Request with object in it and response with object in it..  DataContracts inside of the message contracts ?!?

I've run a few project scenarios and if I pass the parameters (elements of the MessageContract as the method signature defines... its fine ) but it was declared with a object (MessageContract) as the parameter type not its properties.... where are these out parameters and ref parameters coming from ?

I of course also followed a few examples like

http://codeproject.cachefly.net/Articles/664238/Understanding-Contracts-in-WCF

**What I have tried:**

```
Generated Client Proxy :: 

public int RequestResponsePersonaCreate(int RequestId, MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.Persona PersonaObj, out MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.Persona PersonaObjResp) {
MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.MsgRequest inValue = new MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.MsgRequest();
inValue.RequestId = RequestId;
inValue.PersonaObj = PersonaObj;
MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.MsgResponse retVal = ((MsgCtrtCLIENT.servREF.ImsgCtrctServ)(this)).RequestResponsePersonaCreate(inValue);
PersonaObjResp = retVal.PersonaObjResp;
return retVal.ID;
}


//********implementation******
public class msgCtrctServ : ImsgCtrctServ

public MsgResponse RequestResponsePersonaCreate(MsgRequest msgReq)
{
MsgResponse msgRsp = new MsgResponse();

msgRsp.ID = 500;
msgRsp.PersonaObjResp =
new Persona
{
Category = "Dumpling",
Id = 88,
Name = "Pookie",
Toys = new List(),
Title = "Test"
};


return msgRsp;
}

//********interface******

[ServiceContract]
public interface ImsgCtrctServ
{
[OperationContract]
MsgResponse RequestResponsePersonaCreate(MsgRequest msgReq);


//*****messagecontract Response*********

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class MsgResponse
{

private string responseString;
private Persona _persona = new Persona();

[MessageHeader]
public int ID { get; set; }

public bool Success { get; set; }


[MessageBodyMember]
public Persona PersonaObjResp
{
get { return _persona; }
set { _persona = value; }
}

public string ResponseString
{
get { return responseString; }
set { responseString = value; }
}




//*****messagecontract Request*********



[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class MsgRequest
{
[MessageHeader]
public int RequestId { get; set; }

[MessageBodyMember]
   public Persona PersonaObj { get; set; }

//******datacontract********


public class Persona
{

public string Name { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me... a little more stumbling around has unconvered the magic solution from this [StackOverflow WCF Messagecontract-clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567744/wcf-messagecontract-clarification-please)
And [StackOverflow wcf-messagecontract-formatting-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549953/wcf-messagecontract-formatting-issue)

Apparently when generating the client one must dig into that little area where you can force the client to generate the old ASMX style web service or force the lists to be generic instead of defaulting to arrays   and herein lies the magic option ----advanced configuration in Add Service reference (by checking Always generate message contracts)  ..SO credit to 
Ladislav Mrnka answered Jul 4 '11 at 7:08 from the 7549953 post  thank you sir!  And sorry to all for my dumb re-post..
And now the fun part  I must try it !!